# MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413da0c0 that was originally added here

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, logcat, forceclose

I'm experiencing an issue in eclipse stating:

```
MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413da0c0 that was originally added here
```

Has anyone seen this before or know how this issue can be resolved? I've looked over the code quite a few times and I simply do not understand what can be done to resolve it.

LOGCAT:

```
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829): Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413da0c0 that was originally added here
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413da0c0 that was originally added here
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at com.example.test.MainActivity$MyTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:56)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
10-09 17:12:15.630: E/WindowManager(1829):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SOURCE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    String url = "http://examplecloudurl.org/apps/users/results.cfm?lname=BAR&fname=FOO";
    String tr;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            {
                try {




                    String imageURL = "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg";
                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(imageURL));

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                            .execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                    Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                    for (Element row : tableRows) {
                        Elements cells = row.select("td");
                        if (cells.size() > 0) {
                            title = cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                                    + cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(3).text();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }
        }


        public void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            String url = "http://www.juventus.com/wps/poc?uri=wcm:oid:91da6dbb-4089-49c0-a1df-3a56671b7020";

            Document document = manuelRedirectHandler(url);

            Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("juveShareImage");

            for (Element element : elements)
            {
                System.out.println(element.attr("src"));
            }

        }

        private Document manuelRedirectHandler(String url) throws IOException
        {
            org.jsoup.Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")).followRedirects(false).execute();
            int status = response.statusCode();

            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
            {
                String redirectUrl = response.header("location");
                System.out.println("Redirect to: " + redirectUrl);
                return manuelRedirectHandler(redirectUrl);
            }

            return Jsoup.parse(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT (after first response):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    new MyTask().execute(url);
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog prog;

    String title = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        prog.setMessage("Loading....");
        prog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        {
            return title;
        }
    }


    public void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String url = "http://www.juventus.com/wps/poc?uri=wcm:oid:91da6dbb-4089-49c0-a1df-3a56671b7020";

        Document document = manuelRedirectHandler(url);

        Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("juveShareImage");

        for (Element element : elements)
        {
            System.out.println(element.attr("src"));
        }

    }

    private Document manuelRedirectHandler(String url) throws IOException
    {
        org.jsoup.Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")).followRedirects(false).execute();
        int status = response.statusCode();

        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
        {
            String redirectUrl = response.header("location");
            System.out.println("Redirect to: " + redirectUrl);
            return manuelRedirectHandler(redirectUrl);
        }

        return Jsoup.parse(response.body());
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String... params) {
        super.onPostExecute(title);
        prog.dismiss();
        tv.setText(title);

        try {




            String imageURL = "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg";
            HttpGet httpRequest = null;

            httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(imageURL));

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

            Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
            for (Element row : tableRows) {
                Elements cells = row.select("td");
                if (cells.size() > 0) {
                    title = cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                            + cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                            + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                            + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                            + cells.get(3).text();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you closing the `Activity` before the task finishes?

Answer (score 0):

You are grabbing an ImageView and trying to manipulate it in the doInBackground of your AsyncTask.  This is a no-no.

This and all references to it should not be in the doInBackground():

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Read through the [Android documentation for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and also do some googling for some examples.

What you basically want to do is return the bitmap from your doInBackground() to your postExecute() of your AsyncTask.  You can then set the ImageView with the bitmap there.

And why do you have a main() in an android AsyncTask class?